# Embed image doesn't appear discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to collect attachments from a message and then send them in an embed. I've tried this:

```
attachment = message.attachments.first()
url = attachment.url

const embedmem = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#ffffff')
    .setTitle('Title')
    .setDescription('Description')
    .setImage(url)
message.channel.send(embedmem);
```

But no images appeared. Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your variables (such as attachment and URL) using `const`/`let`/`var` etc... (depending on your needs).

```js
const Attachment = message.attachments.first(); // Getting the attachment.

const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // Creating an embed message.
    .setColor("#ffffff")
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setDescription("Description")
    if (Attachment && Attachment.url) {Embed.setImage(Attachment.url)} // If the attachment exists we are adding the image.
message.channel.send(Embed);
```

Comment: I've tried that but the image still hasn't appeared.

Comment: No, the image just doesn't appear like before.

Comment: Does your bot have permission to send embed links and images?

Comment: Yeah, I made the bot send the link by itself and it worked. It's just not working for attachments.

Comment: Can you help with this if you have the time?

Comment: Yeah I'm using v12

Comment: I've tried many times but I cannot reproduce your problem. May I see your entire code?

Comment: Sure. It's too big to put in here so here's a hastebin: https://hastebin.com/xexoqiwapu.js

Comment: Your code is not working because you are deleting the original message, therefore, the attachments are deleted as well.